# how to switch currency depending on the language code in $ _SERVER

Tags: magento2, event-observer, language, currency, currency-symbol

I use a separate translation service, it makes a copy of my frontend and redirects to another domain. I am using language switcher from this service. since they are not related to magento stores I cannot add my own currency for each store

but, to switch the currency, the service focuses on the language code in my variable `$ _SERVER`

`["HTTP_SERVISE_LANGUAGE"]=>  string(2) "fr"`

help implement an observer that will change currency depending on the code that comes into the variable `$_SERVERS`